# Changing colors in a simple shape editior

Tags: colors, editor, shapes

I've made a simple shape editor. I can change colors (used to fill shapes) by click on buttons in a menu bar. The disadvangate of this solving is the fact that the numbers of colors are so restricted. I can't find a better solution for my program. Can somebody help me and give me an idea how can I improve it? I thought about color palette, but I have no idea how can I do this.

The image:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/BXDhUj7.jpg]
("Aktywny kolor" means active colors, and there is the list of colors below, which I can use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a color picker where the colors are distributed on many pixels and not on a very small set of color names. Since you are using applet, you might want to download an [already made color picker](http://www.etn.nl/colorpicker/) compatible with your environment, or you might want to write your own, depending on whether the things you find meet your expectations.